# List of all the applications from App Store

Tags: iphone

I am trying to build a website which will display a list of all the applications from the app store. It is similar to http://iphone.handster.com/. But i am not getting how to get the list of all the apps. Is there any API provided by APPLE to get the list or we have to write some service to get the list ?

Comment: Good Day Sandy you might want to check this link i guess this will help you [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801182/how-can-i-use-appstore-api-to-get-top100-list-what-is-the-common-architecture-t) thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Appstore API to get top100 list? What is the common architecture to build a appstore application website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801182/how-can-i-use-appstore-api-to-get-top100-list-what-is-the-common-architecture-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the data from the rss feeds from the apple store from the link
:-

Top Free Applications:- 
http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=300/xml

Top Paid Applications:-
http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppaidapplications/limit=300/xml

There is a generator in itunes.apple.com which generates the url for the list(based on the type) you want to get. check this [link](http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/) for it.

Comment: They have 100 limit now.