# How to retrieve the list of top 1000 games in the iOS App Store in real-time

Tags: ios, api, charts, app-store

I'd like to retrieve the list of top 1000 apps (specifically games) in the iOS App Store in real-time. This information is public (at least the top 300), but Apple doesn't offer any API or automated way to fetch these lists. Does anyone know a good service for this?

I've listed similar topics in forums below, as well as different useful resources. Most of these help you track your own applications, but I'm interested in **following trends for ALL apps in the App Store**.

Thanks!

Similar topics:

- [How can I use Appstore API to get top100 list? What is the common architecture to build a appstore application website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801182/how-can-i-use-appstore-api-to-get-top100-list-what-is-the-common-architecture-t)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689711/itunes-app-store-api
- http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13167

Solutions:

- http://www.appfigures.com
- http://majicjungle.com
- http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no documented public API, but you can (currently) still get at the data.

You can use wireshark (or similar) to figure out the URL sequences and the user agent that iTunes on a Mac or PC uses to get all the popularity sorted pages that it displays when manually clicking through the pages.  It's all (currently) done in plain HTTP.  You can get 100's of pages for many 1000's of apps this way.  Then parse and decode the XML returned for these URLs to get the app names displayed on each page.  A bunch of perl scripts driving wget or curl might work.

Note that the URLs, user agent and the format of the XML returned often changes when Apple updates iTunes.  So you will need to periodically re-adapt your retrieval mechanism.

Comment: I did the above last year to find my one of my apps down around 5000th in category popularity.  But they changed the format again.

Comment: This method has been failed since Nov 20th, 2014.

Comment: @northtree, do you know of any URL that works now? Can you comment further?

Comment: https://rss.itunes.apple.com/us/?urlDesc=%2Fgenerator By this link you can create url as per your requirement